# Infopath People Picker goes blank when completing

Tags: 2013, infopath, people-picker

I have recently created an infopath 2013 form which connects to our sharepoint 2013 site using an issue tracking app.

I have a number of fields set to use people picker which seem to cause an issue at the moment.  When typing a name on the field and tab or click on the find icon it goes blank.  I will then need to close the form and open again.  Sometimes we have to open a few times before it recognizes the name and allowing us to submit the form. Form uses 2 different views and there a few rules set up within the form but nothing too complicated.

Any ideas on how to overcome this issue?  I have tried to get the answer from forums but no luck so far.

Comment: Open the control properties dialog. On the SharePoint Server tab, does it point to the correct server and site collection?

Comment: it is pointing to the correct server, although it indicates that this option is only used if the form is not published and mine it is a published site.  any other thoughts?  It is becoming a bit of an issue this one for us.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing same problem here.